# Behavior of shuffle on Set vs List using scala.util.Random

Tags: list, scala, random, set, shuffle

```
 scala> Random.shuffle((1 to 10).toSet)
 res10: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 10, 1, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4)

 scala> Random.shuffle((1 to 10).toSet)
 res11: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 10, 1, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4)

 scala> Random.shuffle((1 to 10).toSet)
 res12: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 10, 1, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4)

 scala> Random.shuffle((1 to 10).toList)
 res13: List[Int] = List(3, 9, 8, 5, 7, 6, 10, 2, 1, 4)

 scala> Random.shuffle((1 to 10).toList)
 res14: List[Int] = List(5, 10, 2, 9, 4, 7, 8, 6, 1, 3)

 scala> Random.shuffle((1 to 10).toList)
 res15: List[Int] = List(5, 9, 10, 6, 8, 3, 4, 1, 7, 2)
```

So shuffle can handle Lists just fine, but not sets ?
Can't sets be shuffled ? 
Why is res10 == res11 == res12 ?

Comment: Your complaint is not about the behavior of Random, but rather the behavior of Set. The Set contract does not imply preservation of order -- conveniently allowing for optimizations such as backing the Set with a hashtable -- thus calling toSet is an invitation to re-order your collection.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Scala's sets aren't ordered (just like the mathematical ones). They are iterable, however—you just can't rely on the order that you'll get the items in. Many implementations of sets will iterate the same elements in the same order—i.e.,

```
scala> Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).toList == Set(5, 4, 3, 2, 1).toList
res0: Boolean = true
```

Which explains the effect you're seeing here. You should never rely on this, though—there could be a perfect valid `Set` implementation for which the above wouldn't hold.

Comment: Uh...ok. I accept your explanation, though I don't think Random.shuffle is fulfilling the postcondition here. The shuffle algorithm must provide a random order regardless of the underlying container. Its very easy to provide this behavior. For example: Random.shuffle((1 to 10).toSet) can internally call Random.shuffle((1 to 10).toSet.toList) to get an arbitrary ordering, which can then be shuffled.

Comment: It is a little weird, and I'm not sure why `shuffle` is defined for any `TraversableOnce` (instead of say `Seq`). It's simply not possible to write a version of `shuffle` for sets that would provide a random order, since it doesn't make sense to talk about _any_ kind of order for sets.

Comment: Just saw your comment edit: yes, but `shuffle` returns a collection of the same type as its input, and as soon as you put the shuffled list back into a set you're stuck in the same situation.

Comment: And please don't accept my explanation if it's not clear to you!

Comment: Order does not matter to Set equality: the elements are either present in both sets or one set has one or more element that the other doesn't have. You can think of Set equality as two substractions: `(a -- b).isEmpty && (b -- a).isEmpty`. If this is true, then boths sets have exactly the same elements.

Answer (score 2):

Random is "shuffling" the Set; it just has no visible effect since sets do not have an order. The REPL happens to print the shuffled sets the same way every time:

```
scala> Set(1,2,3,4,5) 
res29: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> Set(5,4,3,2,1)
res30: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> util.Random.shuffle(res30)
res31: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the same thing as the existing answer from three years ago

Comment: I disagree. My answer is not the same and is clearer and easier to understand for a beginner. I would like to hear @kr 's opinion on which answer is more clear. His comment indicates that the other answer was not.

Comment: Since @kr was "Last seen Aug 21 '13 at 22:13" you're not likely to get that. And since he did accept it, I assume he found it clear after the comments.

Comment: For me this answer is much clearer than accepted one